# How can I align my overset to the left?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to create the following effect

[image]

Using the following code:

```
$\{equation\}\overset{N}{i=1}$
```

However, my result is this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can align my overset code to the left, or an alternative option that does as I intend?

Comment: Thank you! I may come here often, if this question is any indicator to how quickly I get stuck on trivial problems...

Comment: Don't worry! This may be not so obvious to newbies, but it's really easy, once you get the feeling.

Comment: Why not `\[
\{equation\}^{N}_{i=1}
\]`?

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, I simply wasn't aware that a subscript and superscript combined would result in that functionality. Your answer is the solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$\{equation\}_{i=1}^{N}$
```

Every math symbol can take subscripts and superscripts, including `\}`.

Opening fences *may* give problems, sometimes, but this is a closing one, so no strange issue.

[image]

Comment: Am I write in thinking you are saying: Give this end bracket a subscript AND a superscript?

Comment: @eygrr Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the fontsize  of the alignment, either use a plain `^{}_{}`, or a `matrix*[l]` environment, or `\Vectorstack` from the `stackengine` package, which allows to easily control the interrow spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

\usepackage{stackengine}

```
\begin{document}

\[ \{\mathsf{equation}\}\begin{matrix*}[l]
  N\\i + 1
\end{matrix*} \]%
\[ \{\mathsf{equation}\}^{N}_{i + 1} \]%
\[\setstackgap{L}{2ex} \{\mathsf{equation}\}\Vectorstack[l]{N {i + 1}}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This answer will be useful for when I'm looking to serve the larger version.

Comment: I've just added another solution with `stackengine`.